# Improving jenkins reliability in randomly failled tests

Tags: testing, selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, reliability

I have a set of +800 selenium tests and because of problems in our application (mostly asynchronicity bugs which we are aware but cannot fix now) they, sometimes, randomly, fail.

We use jenkins for CI and I'd like to know if there is a way to configure jenkins to see the past builds and warn of failing tests only if the same tests fails in the previous builds. This, albeit not a perfect solution, would help mitigate the randomness of tests and the effort to analyse only those that are real bugs.

Any ideias?

Comment: You want save reports after build?

Comment: No. I want jenkins to show me the failed tests according to the present _and_ past build results.

Comment: You do not have enough build history?

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) yet?

Comment: That shows nothing specific to either selenium or strange, random build problems ...